# Angular2 (with D3), 'getBoundingClientRect' typing issue

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I'm getting the error when getting the size of an element:

> error TS2339: Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type
>   'BaseType'.   Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type
>   'Window'

The call I'm making is:

```
let height: number = parseInt(d3.select('#grid').node().getBoundingClientRect().height, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on your own experiment too, pulling out into separate variables:

```
let gridHeight: ClientRect = d3.select('#grid').node().getBoundingClientRect();
let height: number = parseInt(<any>gridHeight.height, 10);
```

Comment: This added another error on top of the current one: `error TS2345: Argument of type 'ClientRect' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'`

Comment: Doesn't seem to like the syntax with that update: `error TS1005: '>' expected` and `error TS1005: ',' expected.`

Comment: I adjusted to this: `let gridRect: ClientRect = d3.select('#grid').node().getBoundingClientRect();` still get the error but it pulls the out `getBoundingClientRect` on its own.

Comment: Yep, would be easier to separate the variable then perform the parseInt() on it.

Comment: turns out `.height` is a number so I didn't have to parse it. However, I did this: `let gridRect: ClientRect = d3.select('#grid').node().getBoundingClientRect()` returns the same error I was having.

Comment: Is #grid an id of an element?

Comment: Yes, it's a container of dynamically added content.

Comment: this seems to work with no errors: `let gridRect: ClientRect = document.getElementById('grid').getBoundingClientRect();`